# matplotlib limit number of y marks for large set of y plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list with several sine-curves. A sine-curve is basically a list of y values. So the loop iterates through each sine-curve and plots its y values. Each sine-curve has its own y values from -1 to 1, but all share the same x values(time)

A sine-curve can have > 10000 plots within 10000 miliseconds. Values are between -1 and 1.

I want all plots to be drawn and visible, however i only want three y-marks/labels to be shown on the left side: -1, 0 and 1.

ylim/set_yticks seem not to work and produce strange results:

```
def plot(self, listOfCols):
    self.figure.clear()
    x=listOfCols[0][1:]
    xi=[i for i in range(0, len(x))]
    plt.xlabel(listOfCols[0][0])
    for i, val in enumerate(listOfCols[1:]):
        y=val[1:]
        ay=self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        plt.ylim(-1,1)
        ay.plot(xi, y, '-')
    self.canvas.draw()
```

[Kind of random values are picked from matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq7VP.png)

Without ylim and stuff:

[To many y marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxmt9.png)

And with `plt.yticks([-1,0,1])`

i get this result:

```
    def plot(self, listOfCols):
    self.figure.clear()
    x=listOfCols[0][1:]
    xi=[i for i in range(0, len(x))]
    plt.xlabel(listOfCols[0][0])
    for i, val in enumerate(listOfCols[1:]):
        y=val[1:]
        ay=self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        plt.yticks([-1,0,1])
        ay.plot(xi, y, '-')
    self.canvas.draw()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHZMf.png)

Somehow matplotlib creates two ranges from 1 to - 1 on the y axies. But i dont know why. The input data is definitly correct.

[Multiple ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jC5m.png)

Comment: Please show us your code. Thanks!

Comment: On first glance, I think your ydata are strings and not numbers, but there is no way to be sure without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There are other very puzzling things with your code. Why are you creating the same `subplot(111)` over and over in a for loop? Why is the plotting done in a loop at all? Again a MVCE is required to help.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was, that ydata was string and not number!

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding:

```
plt.yticks([-1,0,1])
```

Comment: This doesnt work somehow. Ive added a picture in the question so you can see what i mean.Somehow matplotlib creates two ranges from 1 to - 1 on the y axies.